# How do I read a view's bounds in the OnAppearing() method?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

Currently I have this:

```
protected override void OnAppearing()
{
    var collapsedHeight = ReportFormButtonBar.Height;
    var reportFormExpandedPosition = ReportForm.Bounds;
    var reportFormCollapsedPosition = ReportForm.Bounds;

    reportFormCollapsedPosition.Y = ( ReportForm.Height - collapsedHeight );
        reportFormExpandedPosition.Y = 0;

    ReportForm.TranslateTo( reportFormCollapsedPosition.X, reportFormCollapsedPosition.Y, 200, Easing.CubicOut );

    base.OnAppearing();
}
```

Which is supposed to position the ReportForm in a collapsed position. To do that, I need to read some bounds. However, the bounds are all set to x:0, y:0 with width and height to -1. I've been struggling with this for a long while now and can't find any answer.

TLDR: What should I do to be able to read the correct bounds in this method? Or is there some other way to accomplish view setup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To work with view bounds, I would recommend overriding [`OnSizeAllocated`](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/event/Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement.SizeChanged/) or [`SizeChanged`](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/event/Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement.SizeChanged/) event.

```
//in view class
protected override void OnSizeAllocated(double width, double height)
{
    base.OnSizeAllocated(width, height);

    // retreive view bounds here..
}

//OR..

ReportForm.SizeChanged += (sender, e) => {
    if(Width > 0 && Height > 0)
    {
        // retreive view bounds here..    
    }
};
```